# Display additional fields (and sort by) in Entries in Control Panel

Tags: entries, control-panel, sorting

I have created a Calendar channel in the Control Panel.
I have added a field Calendar Date.

Is it possible to add that field to the Entries list and sort by it?

If I use the post date as the calendar date it will not display if it is in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at the moment. Sorting by custom field in the back end entries screen is not yet implemented although I know it is definitely possible in the future based on the way the code is currently laid out.

I would create a front end method to list and sort the entries with links into edit with cpEditUrl

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/categorymodel#cpEditUrl

Comment: Thanks - I suppose it should be possible then on the front end to detect if a user is logged in then display an edit option beside the entry?

Comment: Definitely! thats whats cool about craft! edit entry links everywhere on the frontend! just wrap in an if currentUser.admin :)